# QGIS Layout not exporting although it showed export successfully

Tags: qgis, export

I'm attemptng to export an jpg map from layout using QGIS 3.2.0.
I get the message that the layout has been successfully exported, along with the path, but nothing shows up in the destination specified.
I have tried another computer with QGIS 3.10 (A Coruña) but still not working.
Furthermore, I restarted the program, changed the destination and lower the dpi, nothing helps.

Any ideas?[image: S]

Comment: Have you tried to export your map to another hard drive for example `D:` or to an external hard disk. Maybe there is a write access violation to `C:` drive.

Comment: @ahmadhanb Yes, I tried several different destinations but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to restart your PC.

Comment: @nagib I have even tried another PC... The same.

Comment: Install software pdf creator. That is virtual printer, and when you want export image, you have to print and choose this virual printer to print to *.pdf or *.png or *.jpg. This is first aid.